# Looking to add 150 values to search for within this statement::: If Cell.Value = "5" Then

Tags: excel, vba

I have a mountain of data I need to harvest based on a list of values that could be found within column J. With the 150 or so qualifying values I would like the entire row copied to another sheet within the work book. 
This below gets me close but not sure how to add 150 or so values to find:

```
 For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("J:J")`enter code here`
If Cell.Value = "ABCDEFG" Then
    matchRow = Cell.Row
    Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Example using Match()

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim c As Range, rngTest As Range, rngList As Range

    Set rngList = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("list").Range("A1:A150")

    Set rngTest = Application.Intersect(Sheets(1).Range("J:J"), Sheets(1).UsedRange)

    If Not rngTest Is Nothing Then        
       For Each c In rngTest
            'Does the value in c match any of the values in the
            '   list on sheet "list" range A1:A150 ?
            'If Yes (Match does not return an error) then copy that row
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, rngList, 0)) Then
                c.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(c.Row, 1)
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Im not sure that I phrased my question correctly. Within column J there are many values that I do not need.

Comment: How do I add multiple values to this line? If Cell.Value = "ABCDEFG" Then

Comment: See my added comment.  If that doesn't clear things up then maybe I've completely misunderstood your question.